# Titanium.App.addEventListener results in an "undefined" object application error on ios devices

Tags: ios5, webview, ios6, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am using Titanium.App.addEventlistener to catch events fired from a local webview by  Titanium.App.fireEvent.

In webview:

```
Titanium.App.fireEvent('webviewToTi', {id:0});
```

In app:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('webviewToTi', function(e){
     alert('I am in app.js: ' + e.id);
});
```

This works well in iOS simulator, but when I run it on my ipad I get the Appcelerator red screen of death:

**'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Titanium.App.addEventListener')**

I ran a few different tests with Ti.App.addEventlistener, and even in a stripped down project that contains nothing else I still get this problem.

Does anybody have any idea why this error exists specifically in ios devices but not in simulator?

Can anyone suggest an alternative way to communicate with my webview.

*(Please not the content of the webview is local, not remote, I am aware that this type of communication isn't possible with remote websites)*

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and so I am posting to share what I found out:

It seems that putting code in separate files and using  **Titanium.include** works for the simulator, but not on a iphone or ipad.

In order to get rid of the error, I had to put all my code into one file. This makes it a bit hard to read, and I would prefer a better fix, but this seems to work for now.